# Angular: async | keyvalue --> Property 'X' does not exist on type 'X'

Tags: angular, typescript, templates, asynchronous

I am new to Angular and TypeScript :)
I have a problem that's giving me a headache...

I have the following component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-posts',
  templateUrl: './posts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./posts.component.scss']
})
export class PostsComponent implements OnInit {
        
  analysisType: string = "Posts";
  limit: number = initLimitValue;
      
  posts$!: Observable<Post[]>;
      
  constructor(public dataCollectorService: DataCollectorService) { }
      
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.posts$ = this.dataCollectorService.squeezePosts(this.analysisType, this.limit).pipe(debounceTime(400), distinctUntilChanged());
  }
}
```

This is the template:

```
<div class="posts-div">
    <div *ngFor="let post of posts$ | async | keyvalue">
        {{ post.value.title }}
    </div>
</div>
```

This component is using the following service:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataCollectorService {

  private url = 'http://localhost:8080/mydata/';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
  }


  squeezePosts(analysisType: string, limit: number): Observable<Post[]>{ 
    return this.http.get<Post[]>(`${this.url}${analysisType}/"none"/none"/${limit}`)
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError<Post[]>('squeezePosts', undefined))
    );
  }

  private handleError<T>(operation='operation', result?: T) {
    return (error: any): Observable<T> => {
      console.error(error);
      console.log(operation + ' failled: ' + error.message);
      return of(result as T);
    }
  }
}
```

This is what I get as a response from my localhost server:

```
{
    "0": {
        "title": "0 - My title test",
        "selftext": "0 - My selftext test, My selftext test. My selftext test ..."
    },
    "1": {
        "title": "1 - My title test",
        "selftext": "1 - My selftext test, My selftext test. My selftext test ..."
    }
}
```

and this is my `Post` interface:

```
export interface Post {
    title: string,
    selftext: string
}
```

Finally, this is the error I can't get rid of:

> Property 'title' does not exist on type 'number | Post | (() => string) | (() => string) | (() => Post | undefined) | ((...items: Post[]) => number) | { (...items: ConcatArray[]): Post[]; (...items: (Post | ConcatArray<...>)[]): Post[]; } | ... 25 more ... | ((searchElement: Post, fromIndex?: number | undefined) => boolean)'.
>
> Property 'title' does not exist on type 'number'.

Can you please help out on this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your response, it is **not an array of Post (`Post[]`)**.

But it is set of **key-value pair/dictionary** with **key as `string` type** and **value as `Post` type**.

```
{
    "0": {
        "title": "0 - My title test",
        "selftext": "0 - My selftext test, My selftext test. My selftext test ..."
        }
    "1": {
        "title": "1 - My title test",
        "selftext": "1 - My selftext test, My selftext test. My selftext test ..."
        }
}
```

---

### Solution 1: `Map<string, Post>`

Declare `posts$` with `Observable<Map<string, Post>>` type.

> data-collector.service.ts

```js
squeezePosts(analysisType: string, limit: number): Observable<Map<string, Post>> {
    return this.http
       .get<Map<string, Post>>(`${this.url}${analysisType}/"none"/none"/${limit}`)
       .pipe(catchError(this.handleError<Map<string, Post>>('squeezePosts', undefined)));
}
```

> posts.component.ts

```js
posts$!: Observable<Map<string, Post>>;
```

[Sample Solution 1 on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hg4ct6)

---

### Solution 2: `KeyValuePair<Post>`

- Create interface `KeyValuePair` with generic type.
- Declare `posts$` with `Observable<KeyValuePair<Post>>` type.

> key-value-pair.ts

```js
export interface KeyValuePair<T> {
  [key: string]: T;
}
```

> data-collector.service.ts

```js
import { KeyValuePair } from '../models/key-value-pair';

squeezePosts(
    analysisType: string,
    limit: number
  ): Observable<KeyValuePair<Post>> {
     return this.http
       .get<KeyValuePair<Post>>(`${this.url}${analysisType}/"none"/none"/${limit}`)
       .pipe(catchError(this.handleError<KeyValuePair<Post>>('squeezePosts', undefined)));
}
```

> posts.component.ts

```js
import { KeyValuePair } from '../models/key-value-pair';

posts$!: Observable<KeyValuePair<Post>>;
```

[Sample Solution 2 on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4nkokm)

Comment: That was exactly it. Thanks a lot.